# MongoDB GeoJSON $near AssertionError

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, geojson

My Angular frontend is returning an `AssertionError` after making a request to my Node/Mongo backend when trying to display map markers on a MapBox GL JS map:

```
actual: false
code: "ERR_ASSERTION"
expected: true
generatedMessage: true
name: "AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]"
operator: "=="
```

This is for an Angular 7 app using a Node/MongoDB backend. I have a collection of "Users" with GeoJSON points. I have tried using the `db.collection.find()` method with `$near` and `$geoNear`, both of which produce the error. If I remove these expressions and do a plain `db.collection.find({})`, the response returns as expected.

Also, I am able to make the request using a REST client (Restlet for Chrome) with the `$geoNear` express and the results are returning properly.

I have also looked as best as I can on Google and Stackoverflow for an answer to no avail.

users.js route:

```
router.get('/trucks', (req, res, next) => {
    User
    .find({
        'geometry': {
            $nearSphere: {
                $geometry: {
                    type : "Point",
                    coordinates: [
                        parseFloat(req.query.lng),
                        parseFloat(req.query.lat),
                    ]
                },
                $maxDistance : 100000
            }
        }
    })
    .then((users, err) => {
        if (err) res.json({success: false, message: 'There was a problem with the lookup.'});
        if (!users) res.json({success: true, message: "Sorry, we couldn't find anyone in your area."})
        let results = users.map(user=> {
            let userResult = {
                id: user._id,
                name: user.name,
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email,
                geometry: {
                    type: user.geometry.type,
                    coordindates: user.geometry.coordinates
                }
            }
            return userResult;
        });

        res.json({
            success: true,
            users: results
        });
    })
    .catch(err =>
        res.json(err)
    );
})
```

map.service.getMarkers():

```
  getMarkers(): Observable<GeoJson> {
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/users');
  }
```

GeoJson class:

```
export class GeoJson implements IGeoJson {
  type = 'Feature';
  geometry: IGeometry;

  constructor(coordinates, public properties?) {
    this.geometry = {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: coordinates
    }
  }
}
```

map.component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.markers = this.mapService.getMarkers();
    this.initMap();
  }

...

private initMap() {
    // ommited code to get location using navigator geolocation API

    this.setMap()
  }

...

setMap() {
    // ommited code to style map

      this.markers.subscribe((result) => {
        let markers = [];

        result.trucks.forEach(truck => {
           console.log(user.geometry.coordindates);
           let coordinates = user.geometry.coordindates;
           let newMarker = new GeoJson(coordinates, { message: user.name });
           markers.push(newMarker)
        })

        let data = new FeatureCollection(markers)
        this.source.setData(data)
      })

    })
}
```

I expect to get a response containing my users so I can map their location. Like I said above, I can make a request using a REST client and everything works as expect. Also, the generic `db.collection.find({})` will return all of my documents and I can then map then. The problem seems to be with:

```
'geometry': {
            $nearSphere: {
                $geometry: {
                    type : "Point",
                    coordinates: [
                        parseFloat(req.query.lng),
                        parseFloat(req.query.lat),
                    ]
                },
                $maxDistance : 100000
            }
        }
```

[Sample document from MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOdQt.png)

[Successful response using REST client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvDtQ.png)

[Working result with the `$geoNear` expression removed from find()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43ouP.png)

Comment: This isn't a MongoDB error, but would appear to rather be coming from the implemented Mapbox functions, which you don't actually show any usage in your code here. As far as I can see, everything *up until* the `setMap()` method should be working fine. So the error is likely producing in the code which is working with the results **after** the data is retrieved to the client. Note though that `subscribe()` calls really belong in an initializer function, and not something repeatedly called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Very simple fix that I was overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

I completely overlooked the fact that I was not sending any coordinates with the request to my Node backend:

`return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/users');`

should be:

`return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/users?lng=&lat=');`

This solved my issue.